# row_number with rank variable doesn't work

Tags: mysql, ranking, row-number

I want to get the ranking of the players in a game system, but I can't get it right to work with the @rank variable. Where is the problem here?

First table: 'player'

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | name     | points | 
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | Player 1 |   100  |
| 2  | Player 2 |   250  |
| 3  | Player 3 |    57  |
| 4  | Player 4 |   578  |
| 5  | Player 5 | 12580  |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Second table: 'guild'

```
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
| 1  | FirstClass |
+----+------------+
```

Third table: 'guild_player_cross'

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | guild_fk | player_fk | 
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1        | 2         |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

Now I want to get the players ranking list sorted by their points.

Query Statement:

```
SELECT 
    @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank,
    p.name,
    p.points,
    g.name AS guild
FROM player AS p
LEFT JOIN guild_player_cross AS gp ON p.id = gp.player_fk
LEFT JOIN guild AS g ON gp.guild_fk = g.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT @rank := 0
) AS tblRank
ORDER BY p.points DESC
```

But the result isn't that, what I thought, because the ranking number aren't correct.:/

Result:

```
+------+----------+--------+-------------+
| rank | name     | points | guild       | 
+------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 5    | Player 5 | 12580  | NULL        |
+------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 4    | Player 4 |   578  | NULL        |
+------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 1    | Player 2 |   250  | FirstClass  |
+------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 2    | Player 1 |   100  | NULL        |
+------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 3    | Player 3 |    57  | NULL        |
+------+----------+--------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Order by is performed after rank was added,

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank,
    x.*
FROM (
SELECT
    p.name,
    p.points,
    g.name AS guild
FROM player AS p
LEFT JOIN guild_player_cross AS gp ON p.id = gp.player_fk
LEFT JOIN guild AS g ON gp.guild_fk = g.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT @rank := 0
) AS tblRank
ORDER BY p.points DESC) x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT 
   @rank := @rank + 1,
    p.name,
    p.points,
    ( 
        SELECT g.name 
        FROM guild_player_cross AS gp 
        LEFT JOIN guild AS g ON gp.guild_fk = g.id 
        WHERE p.id = gp.player_fk
    ) AS guild
FROM player AS p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT @rank := 0
) AS tblRank
ORDER BY p.points DESC;
```

I have put the join into a subquery for not interfere with the order.

I hope you helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way without variables.  This will offer better performance in many cases where there are a lot of things to rank.

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(points, points_list) AS rank, p.name, p.points, g.name AS guild
FROM player AS p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT points ORDER BY points DESC) AS points_list FROM player) points_list
LEFT JOIN guild_player_cross AS gp ON p.id = gp.player_fk
LEFT JOIN guild AS g ON gp.guild_fk = g.id
ORDER BY rank
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Not sure on performance (I am going to have a play with it). A possible issue is if multiple players have the same score. Your DISTINCT would render them both ranked the same and with no gap afterwards, but removing the DISTINCT would result in them both ranked the same but with a gap in the ranking afterwards.

Comment: Quick play on an existing table I have with ~290k records on it. A solution based on your idea takes ~8 seconds while the solution based on a variable takes ~5 seconds. Interesting. One potential issue is the max length of the GROUP_CONCAT result (defaults to 1024 I think).

Comment: @kickstart, your mileage may vary; it's an alternative that might be better, but probably requires some extra care - at least an index on the column to be ranked.

Comment: Aye, it is an interesting idea. The index will be used to order the grouped field, but not the FIND_IN_SET.